# How can I get user input in a Python Discord Bot (Rewrite)?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot that I'm making on Python 3.8.5. I am printing this menu via the proper syntax and commands. Now I want the user to type number 1 or 2 depending on what option he wants to select. Here is my code:

```
    async def menu(self, ctx):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Heartbeat Menu",
            description = "Select and enter a number.\n 1. Check Status of Heartbeat\n 2. Hearbeat Check"
        )
        sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It works properly. What code should be written that when the user types 1 or 2, the bot recognizes that and prints something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def menu(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()

    embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Heartbeat Menu",
            description = "Select and enter a number.\n 1. Check Status of Heartbeat\n 2. Hearbeat Check"
        )
    sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content in ["1", "2"]
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    if msg.content == "1":
        #code for number 1
    else:
        #code for number 2
```

I used [client.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) method to wait for the user input and the `check()` function inside the `menu` function will check for the right `user , channel , message is 1/2` and if it is satisfied, then the `#code for number 1` or `#code for number 2` will be executed! if you still have trouble understanding i recommend you to read the document!

Comment: I tried running the code, it gives me an

`else:
  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block 
`